# connectTimeout more than 30 seconds does not work for OKHTTP

Tags: okhttp

I am trying to set connectTimeout to 2 minutes, but still the tries fails after 30 seconds only.

My client looks like this:

```
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .callTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build();

public Call callReq(Callback callback) {


    Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://203.0.113.1");

    //Create request builder
    final Request request = builder
            .build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);

    call.enqueue(callback);
    return call;
}
```

The failure response of this call I am receiving in 30 seconds. I wanted that to wait for 2 minutes. It works if I reduce the timeout to 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are hitting some additional platform timeouts, e.g. my test timed out after 1:15.

```
package okhttp3.curl

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.Response
import okhttp3.logging.LoggingEventListener
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

fun main() {
  val listener = LoggingEventListener.Factory()
  val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .eventListenerFactory(listener)
      .callTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
      .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
      .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
      .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
      .build()
  val response: Response = client.newCall(
        Request.Builder().url("http://203.0.113.1").build()).execute()

  println(response.request.url)
}
```

Output

```
Mar 29, 2020 12:33:58 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [72 ms] connectStart: /203.0.113.1:80 DIRECT
Mar 29, 2020 12:35:14 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [75599 ms] connectFailed: null java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /203.0.113.1:80
Mar 29, 2020 12:35:14 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [75601 ms] callFailed: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /203.0.113.1:80
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /203.0.113.1:80
```