# Java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed

Tags: java, retrofit2, okhttp

I see this issue when calling an external sandbox. I discovered it's happening with java versions. Has anyone seen this issue before and resolved it?
This happens intermittently.

Sandbox returns 200 and throws an error when parsing the response

java version:  1.8.0_275 + sandbox calls => not working

java version: 1.8.0_202 + sandbox calls => works well

Using retrofit 2.3.0, Okhttp 3.8.0

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:967)
    at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:79)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:180)
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:216)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Writer.rstStream(Http2Writer.java:152)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection.writeSynReset(Http2Connection.java:315)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.close(Http2Stream.java:226)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.cancelStreamIfNecessary(Http2Stream.java:454)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSource.close(Http2Stream.java:428)
    at okio.ForwardingSource.close(ForwardingSource.java:43)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec$StreamFinishingSource.close(Http2Codec.java:199)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.close(RealBufferedSource.java:455)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.close(RealBufferedSource.java:455)
    at okio.InflaterSource.close(InflaterSource.java:126)
    at okio.GzipSource.close(GzipSource.java:182)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.close(RealBufferedSource.java:455)
    at okio.ForwardingSource.close(ForwardingSource.java:43)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.close(RealBufferedSource.java:455)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.close(RealBufferedSource.java:443)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implClose(StreamDecoder.java:378)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.close(StreamDecoder.java:193)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.close(InputStreamReader.java:199)
    at okhttp3.ResponseBody$BomAwareReader.close(ResponseBody.java:258)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._closeInput(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:193)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase.close(ParserBase.java:368)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1622)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1203)
    at retrofit2.converter.jackson.JacksonResponseBodyConverter.convert(JacksonResponseBodyConverter.java:32)
    at retrofit2.converter.jackson.JacksonResponseBodyConverter.convert(JacksonResponseBodyConverter.java:23)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:112)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:141)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at au.com.auspost.utils.MDCUtils.lambda$mdcRunnable$0(MDCUtils.java:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: There isn't anough to go on here.  Perhaps provide the output of event listener in both cases like https://stackoverflow.com/a/60913612/1542667

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved after migrating the retrofit2 library to version 2.8.1. After migrating to retrofit2 library to the latest, we came across the certification verification issues. We have resolved the certification issue by generating new certs.